# Add a close button in native barcode scanner

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic3, barcode-scanner

I am trying to create a barcode scanner app, so i followed this [link in ionic](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/barcode-scanner/) it woks fine but i need a close button on the camera screen so that i can close the camera if its not necessary 
could someone help me with this

my ionic info
Ionic:

ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.1.2
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Cordova:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.1 (cordova-lib@8.1.0)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.1
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.1.4, (and 10 other plugins)

System:

NodeJS : v8.12.0
   npm    : 6.4.1

phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner 8.0.0 "BarcodeScanner"

Comment: Take plugin clone from github and start modifying it for android and iOS platform

Comment: could you share more details about modifying the plugin @PareshGami

Comment: Haven't used this one. I'm using *phonegap-plugin-qrscanner*, it launches scanner below the web view so you can put custom html elements on top of it. Perhaps this one works similarly.

Comment: @YokeshVaradhan Cannot explain all here. You need to do native code in JAVA/Android and for iOS objective-c probably.

Answer (score 1):

## Customize phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner

in project root directory...

#### 1- create directory and clone plugin

$ mkdir customPlugins

$ cd customPlugins

$ git clone https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner.git

$ cd ..

#### 2- Remove older plugins

check if phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner  is in plugins, also remove possible older references in config.xml or package.json.

$ ionic cordova plugin rm phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner

#### 3- Add plugin

$ ionic cordova plugin add './customPlugins/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/'

#### 4- run in device to check that is working.

## How to customize camera overlay in Android

Here is the link to the Android barcode scanner repository:  phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner -> src -> android -> README

#### 1 - Clone repository

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/barcodescanner-lib-aar and open it in android  studio

Camera Overlay layout is capture.xml in res -> layout folder and it's controller is CaptureActivity.java in java -> client -> android.

#### 2- Do whatever you want... & Generate your new Library

go to root project folder -> barcodescanner -> build -> outputs -> aar -> delete folder or content

go to gradle tools window (usually top right corner of android studio) and get execute task build

barcodescanner-lib-aar -> barcodescanner -> Tasks -> build (double click)

#### 3- Open new generated aar file  (barcodescanner-release.aar)

barcodescanner -> build -> outputs -> car

#### 4- Go to ionic project and find barcodescanner-release-2.1.5.aar in customPlugin/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner...

change barcodescanner-release.aar name to barcodescanner-release-2.1.5.aar and replace it in customPlugin/...

#### 5- remove old plugin

$ ionic cordova plugin rm phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner 
            and re add it again

$ ionic cordova plugin add './customPlugins/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/'

#### 6- Check if everything it's working again (maybe have to remove platforms and add them again)

### For iOS is you can refer this link

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-change-barcode-scanner-overlay-img-when-scanning/86095

Comment: It works perfectly in android. Can you please detail it for iOS as well?

Comment: It's a bit different in iOS but is easier. at the end you have to modify  CDVBarcodeScanner.mm adding layouts programatically. Don't remember exactly which line of code should you add your views or overlay, but I think there is some comments in the forum.

Comment: Yes I did check the forum link which you have shared. But the links been shared are outdated. It would be helpful if you could provide any steps on how to fork the plugin in ios same as android. Thanks!

Comment: you don't need to fork the plugin for ios just open those files which should be inside folder /plugins/phonegap..... and modify them inside. I am sorry I could not help you more but I am not working with this techs right now and I don't have an example

Comment: Thankyou for the info! Let me try modifying the files directly.

Answer (score 0):

[Android] The way you can close the scanner is by pressing the back button on the device:

```
constructor(public platform: Platform) {
 this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
  this.navCtrl.pop();
 });
}
```